# How to check for app updates

Tags: android, updates

Im working on my new app and i want it to check for new versions every time the app is started i have been reading other threads and tuts and i know that i need to check with a file on a server and i have created a file for the app to compare with and now i need to know how to make my app check for the update and i have also try other methods but they didn't work that's why im asking here so thanks in advance.

main activity

```
package com.example.update;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you just left blank for others to fill? :)

Comment: oh no i left that there from before when i was trying other methods, its just so i could quickly see were to place code.

Comment: so can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Place XML on your server, with version info, then retrieve it and compare to your version on Android app, and act accordingly.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Comment: how would i compare ect... im fairly new android programming